# How to ROT13 encode in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rot13

The Python 3 documentation has rot13 listed on its [codecs page](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/codecs.html).

I tried encoding a string using rot13 encoding:

```
import codecs
s  = "hello"
os = codecs.encode( s, "rot13" )
print(os)
```

This gives a `unknown encoding: rot13` error. Is there a different way to use the in-built rot13 encoding? If this encoding has been removed in Python 3 (as Google search results seem to indicate), why is it still listed in Python3 documentation?

Comment: Did you try just `s.encode("rot13")` or `s.encode("rot_13")`? I don't think there is any such thing as `codecs.encode`, just `codecs.Codec().encode`

Comment: agf: The codecs.Codec().encode() function only takes in string input, there is no parameter to pass in the encoding type.

Comment: You shouldn't shadow `os`. ಠ_ಠ

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Aha! I thought it had been dropped from Python 3, but no - it is just that the interface has changed, because a codec has to return bytes (and this is str-to-str).

This is from http://www.wefearchange.org/2012/01/python-3-porting-fun-redux.html :

```
import codecs
s   = "hello"
enc = codecs.getencoder( "rot-13" )
os  = enc( s )[0]
```

Answer (score 25):

In Python 3.2+, there is [`rot_13` str-to-str codec](http://ideone.com/8OTu6t):

```
import codecs

print(codecs.encode("hello", "rot-13")) # -> uryyb
```

Answer (score 1):

`rot_13` was dropped in Python 3.0, then added back in v3.2. `rot13` was added back in v3.4.

`codecs.encode( s, "rot13" )` works perfectly fine in Python 3.4+

Actually, now you can use any punctuation character between `rot` and `13` now, including:

`rot-13`, `rot@13`, `rot#13`, etc.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#text-transforms

> New in version 3.2: Restoration of the rot_13 text transform.
> Changed in version 3.4: Restoration of the rot13 alias.

Answer (score 0):

```
def rot13(message):
    Rot13=''
    alphabit = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    for i in message:
        if i in alphabit:
            Rot13 += alphabit[alphabit.index(i) + 13]
        else:
            Rot13 += i
    return Rot13
```

The code is very large , but I'm just learning

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install python library - https://pypi.org/project/endecrypt/

**pip install endecrypt            (windows)**

**pip3 install endecrypt           (linux)**

then,

```py
from endecrypt import cipher

message_to_encode = "Hello World"
conversion = 'rot13conversion'

cipher.encode(message_to_encode, conversion )
# Uryyb Jbeyq

message_to_decode = "Uryyb Jbeyq"

cipher.decode(message_to_decode, conversion)
# Hello World
```