# Basic Encryption in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to explore some encryption types in python. Could anyone provide me with some beginner encryption code? Thanks for any help. I've already tried changing the length of the message, but that didn't work. Please help!

Comment: Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/12525165/2629998.

Comment: https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Hacking Ciphers](http://inventwithpython.com/hackingciphers.pdf) is a great resource! Here is some example code.

```
import sys
import cmd




message = cmd.raw_input("Enter something to encypt: ")
translated = '' 

for i in range(len(message)):
    translated = translated + message[i] 
    i = i - 1 
print(translated)
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
x="hello world".encode("rot-13")
print x
print x.decode("rot-13")
```

Comment: Hi, I added parentheses to the print (i'm using python 3.3) and i got this error message:
    
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python33/encryptiontest.py", line 1, in <module>
    x="hello world".encode("rot-13")
TypeError: encoder did not return a bytes object (type=str)
>>>

Comment: you didnt specify that this was python 3 ... yeah it works differently there ...

Comment: see this answer for python3 http://stackoverflow.com/a/10576397/541038

Comment: Isn't this for string encoding (like going from utf to ascii) not encryption?

Comment: meh rot13 is simple encryption ...