# Decode python rot13 string

Tags: python, rot13

I've a `rot13` encoded string in python and I've to decode it:

```
"Gur dhvpx oebja sbk whzcrq bire gur ynml qbt"
```

Is it possible to do in python? I can't find any method to do it.

Please help!

This is what I've tried:

```
s = "Gur dhvpx oebja sbk whzcrq bire gur ynml qbt"
s1 = ""
for i in range(len(s)):
    c = s[i]
    if c >= 'a' and c <= 'm': c += 13
    elif c > 'A' and c < 'M': c += 13
    elif c >= 'n' and c < 'z': c -= 13
    elif c >= 'N' and c <= 'Z': c -= 13
    s1 += c
    print(c)
print(s1)
```

Comment: No that is completely impossible. The fact that there is no method to do this also means that you can not do it yourself... :)

Comment: added to the question what I've tried @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: nope, I need to decode rot13 encoded string not encode it @KlausD.

Comment: @user8852303: since the alphabet has 26 letters, encoding and decoding is exactly the same operation.

Comment: Then i recommend that you get known to ROT13 at first. There will be a large surprise, I promise. You might also just give it a try.

Comment: Is your code functional? If it's not, change every line of `c += 13` and `c -= 13 ` with `c = chr(ord(c) + 13)` and `c = chr(ord(c) - 13)` respectively. That should work.

Comment: @VasilisG. idk, ok let me try..

Comment: @user8852303 lol,you should definitely give it a try!

Comment: Don't roll back my edit. There's no need for that sort of language (even hidden like that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To decode a `rot13` encoded string, say `s`, simply take `rot13` of the string once again, i.e. compute `rot13(s)`.

If you are not familiar how to compute `rot13` in python, try googling a bit and you'll surely find one. I googled and found a solution that works pretty well : https://stackoverflow.com/a/3269756/3293087 [Note that it works only on python2 and not python3 since `string.maketrans` was removed from python3.]

I'll write the code here for completeness :

```
# Python 2 solution
import string
rot13Table = string.maketrans( 
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMabcdefghijklmNOPQRSTUVWXYZnopqrstuvwxyz", 
    "NOPQRSTUVWXYZnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMabcdefghijklm")
rot13 = lambda s : string.translate(s, rot13Table)

print rot13("Hello World!") 
# Outputs "Uryyb Jbeyq!"
```

**Note** : I'm not going to write the decoded string corresponding to what the OP originally posted, since its quite offensive and homophobic. Anyone interested can do it themselves.

**Update** : I also found a solution that works for python 2 & 3 both from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10576347/how-to-rot13-encode-in-python3). It turns out there is a builtin `rot13` encoder in python in the `codecs` module :

```
# Python 2 & 3 compatible
import codecs
rot13 = lambda s : codecs.getencoder("rot-13")(s)[0]

# Answer
rot13("Gur dhvpx oebja sbk whzcrq bire gur ynml qbt")
```

**Update 2** : Since the OP is adamant to know the answer and does not seem to have python installed, I have a created JS solution  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zPYVQP. Others please proceed with caution.

Comment: take rot13 again, thanks for the great explanation @AbhishekKedia, i would appreciate if you could post the output as well. thanks again.

Comment: don't you have installed on your machine? ;)

Comment: The `string` library has been replaced with the `str` global in Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
utf8 = str.maketrans(
    # this are the related alphabets
    "NOPQRSTUVWXYZnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMabcdefghijklm",
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMabcdefghijklmNOPQRSTUVWXYZnopqrstuvwxyz",
)  
print(str.translate("Gur dhvpx oebja sbk whzcrq bire gur ynml qbt", utf8))
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Its good to have a description along with the output of the code as mentioned above.