# Short Rot (N) decode function in python

Tags: python, decode, encode

I'm kinda new to python and I'm wondering how I can turn this rot (n) encode function

```
def rot_encode(n):
    from string import ascii_lowercase as lc, ascii_uppercase as uc
    lookup = str.maketrans(lc + uc, lc[n:] + lc[:n] + uc[n:] + uc[:n])
    return lambda s: s.translate(lookup)

print(rot_alpha(13)('Hello World'))
```

To a decode function

I don't want to use the built-in functionality of python to encode or decode, I want to recreate it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you know how `maketrans` and `translate` work here?

Comment: No, I found this online and was thinking how I could switch it around. (still a noob :p)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ROT13 encode in Python3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10576347/how-to-rot13-encode-in-python3)

Comment: I want to recreate it myself instead of using a built-in function :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to recreate anything. Just shift the letters in the *other* direction, i.e. instead of `rot_encode(13)`, call `rot_encode(-13)` to decode the previously encoded string.

```
x = rot_encode(13)('Hello World')
y = rot_encode(-13)(x)
print(x) # Uryyb Jbeyq
print(y) # Hello World
```

Of course, you can also wrap this into a `rot_decode` function if you prefer.

```
def rot_decode(n):
    return rot_encode(-n)
```

Comment: Addendum: Of course, in the special case of ROT13 not even this is necessary, as 13 is exactly the half of 26 (the letters in the alphabet), and thus encoding twice will also decode the string, i.e. `rot13(rot13(x)) == x`.